# Landau Notation: Sum of Big O <= Big O of Sum

Tags: runtime

I would like to show that:
O(f_1(n)  + f_2(n)    +  .. + f_k(n)) <= 
O(f_1(n)) + O(f_2(n)) + ... + O(f_k(n)) is true.

My intuition why inequality holds is that in both directions:

<=: We sum up all the constants of the Os on the LHS and put them into the O() on RHS.

Now im not sure whether maybe even equality holds.

BTW: I'm aware that O(f(n)) is a actually a set, so >= is an abuse of notation.

Thanks, Andy

Comment: Are you trying find out if the bounding of all the functions is less than the bounding of each individual function?  You would need to bound the right side together which would then give you the same answer as the left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

In [image: f_1(n) + f_2(n) + .. + f_k(n)] there will be a dominant function  [image: f_x(n)]

So [image: O(f_1(n) + f_2(n) + .. + f_k(n)) \in O(f_x(n))]

And conversely [image: f_x(n)]  is dominated by [image: f_1(n) + f_2(n) + .. + f_k(n)]

So [image: O(f_x(n)) \in O(f_1(n) + f_2(n) + .. + f_k(n))]

And then you get equality

Comment: thanks:
in the last formula it should be an equlity not an elementOf sign right?

Comment: Im still confused with the elementOf, shouldnt it be subsetEq?

Comment: Yes you're right, dumb mistake on my part. I'll leave it at this and people can just read the comments for the correction